# android replace image in the gallery view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gallery

I am trying to extend Gallery so the selected image/view can be replaced by another one (not in the gallery). This is needed to make the Gallery functions as a button list.Because one button has on/off function, so I need to replace the on image with a off image in that case.

Following code doesn't work, the attach... method returns no error, but does't replace the image either.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ChangeableGallery extends Gallery {

    public ChangeableGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void replace(View v, int position, ViewGroup.LayoutParams param){
        attachViewToParent(v,position, param);
    }
```

...

In the event handling:

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // iSwitcher.setImageResource(pics[position]);
        if (position == parent.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
            gallery.replace(imageAdapter.getButtonImage(), position,new Gallery.LayoutParams(300, 240));
        }
    }
});
```

Someone can help on it? Thanks!

Comment: after looking into the api documentation, it seems it is not possible while the underlying AdapterView doesn't allow it.